# Is there a Numpy array broadcasting expression simpler than this list comprehension?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, array-broadcasting

In this code snippet:

```
triangles = np.float32([[[0, -2], [-2, 3], [1, 1]], [[0, -1], [-1, 3], [1, 1]]])
centers = np.average(triangles, axis=1)
samples = np.float32([t-centers[i] for i, t in enumerate(triangles)])
```

I would like to express `samples` as an array broadcast subtraction, i.e. something similar to `triangles-centers`, which doesn't work due to:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3,2) (2,2)
```

Is there a simpler way to define `samples` than a list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want.  Just reshape the centers to match the row size.

```
samples = triangles - centers.reshape(triangles.shape[0],-1,triangles.shape[2])
```

Comment: Thank you rejiggling my memory. This form is more concise: `centers[:, None, :]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) with `keepdims=True` to keep a length-1 dimension in the axis you're taking the mean over:

```
samples = triangles - np.mean(triangles, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by an answer above from @Tim Roberts:

```
triangles = np.float32([[[0, -2], [-2, 3], [1, 1]], [[0, -1], [-1, 3], [1, 1]]])
centers = np.average(triangles, axis=1)
samples = triangles-centers[:, None, :]
```